# Repeated values count as single value of combobox in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Here is my Sample code consisting of a Datagrid where in two Comboboxes columns (Status and Present Status) are need to be counted depending on status changed in the datagrid

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <staticData:StatusList x:Key="StatusList"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <my:DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,-6,0,6">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Subject" Width="*"/>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" 
                                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RaisedBy}" Header="Raised By" Width="100"/>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PresentStatus" Width="100">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" 
                                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
</Grid>`
```

C# Code

```
public class StatusList : List<string>
    {
        public StatusList()
        {
            this.Add("Assigned");
            this.Add("Closed");
            this.Add("In Progress");
            this.Add("Open");
            this.Add("Resolved");
        }
    }
```

so finally I need when saving the datagrid data I need to count the Status.  If status values i.e. similar value selected multiple number of times then it should return as single count.  For example, suppose 3 comboboxes are selected, 1 is Open, 2 is Resolved and 3 is Open, then count should be 2 because for open it should count as single value (or count) when multiple times same value selected.

**EDIT:** Here I have tried code as the combobox Status is editable so if change the values and repeated values should be counted as one value but I am not sure of it.

```
bool isDuplicate;
int count;
for (int nbRow = 0; nbRow < dgData.Rows.Count; nbRow++)
{
    for (int nbRowCompare = nbRow; nbRowCompare < dgData.Rows.Count; nbRowCompare++)
    {
        isDuplicate = true;
        for (int nbCol = 0; nbCol < dgData.Rows[nbRow].Cells.Count; nbCol++)
        {
            if (dgData[nbCol, nbRow].Value != dgData­[nbCol, nbRowCompare])
            {
                isDuplicate = false;
                count++;
                break;     //Exit for each column if they are not duplicate
            }
        }

        if (isDuplicate)
        {
            //Do something
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here i have tried code as the combobox Status is editable so if change the values and repeated values should be counted as one value but iam not sure of it please help me in this way

`bool isDuplicate;
int count;
 for(int nbRow = 0; nbRow < dgData.Rows.Count; nbRow++){for(int nbRowCompare = nbRow; nbRowCompare < dgData.Rows.Count; nbRowCompare++){isDuplicate = true;
for(int nbCol = 0; nbCol < dgData.Rows[nbRow].Cells.Count; nbCol++)
{if(dgData[nbCol, nbRow].Value != dgData­[nbCol, nbRowCompare]){isDuplicate = false;
count++;break;     //Exit for each column if they are not duplicate
}}if(isDuplicate){//Do something count++;}}}`

Comment: Hi Honey, your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you provide an example of what output you're getting, and what your expected output should be?

Comment: for example 4 comboboxes are selected 1row- open 2row-Resolved 3row-Closed 4row-open
So i need these selected comboboxes count as above count should be 4 but Open status is repeated so count should be 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a count of the number of distinct `Status` values used by the various rows shown in your DataGrid.

Your DataGrid is presumably showing an `ObservableCollection` (or some other collection) of objects, one for each row of the table.  (You don't show any value for the `ItemsSource` in your code sample, but I'll assume there is one.)   If this list is called `items`, and you have `using System.Linq;`, you can get a list of distinct statuses using:

```
List<string> distinctStatuses = items.Select(item => item.Status)
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .ToList();
```

If you only want the count, you can simplify this further:

```
int distinctStatusCount = items.Select(item => item.Status).Distinct().Count();
```

I can't be so sure about your `PresentStatus` column, as that is bound to the same column as your `Status` so it will only show the same data.  The `PresentStatus` column in your DataGrid is also missing its `CellTemplate`.